# Why NSString autorelease in every cycle of a for loop without an @autoreleasepool

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my test code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
    NSString *string = @"Abc";
    string = [string lowercaseString];
    string = [string stringByAppendingString:@"xyz"];
}
```

In ARC environment,the loop will not make the memory explode.In my case,it just cost 1.2MB RAM to run this loop.

But in MRC,the loop will make the memory explode unless use a @autoreleasepool code block.What makes me confused is there are many articles say that it is needed to put the codes in a @autoreleasepool when the codes in a for loop. but in this case,it doesn't matter without the @autoreleasepool.Please help me with this.thx.

update:
if I write the code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"];
}
```

the code will make the memory explode both in ARC and MRC. why？

```
stringWithFormat:
```

also return a autorelease object. I am puzzled by this...

Comment: Wait, are you trying to do this manually? ARC came our 4 years ago. I recommend you keep it enabled. It handles memory management under the hood, so you don't have to autorelease or full-on release yourself.

Comment: The reason it explodes if you use it in a non-arc environment is because you are not freeing any memory. Each loop keeps taking space up. In ARC, it's taken care of automatically. There are implicit (hidden) autorelease pools and calls to autorelease, so it's happening under the hood automatically.

Comment: ARC probably inserts a -release, not an -autorelease when it can.

Comment: One way to know would be to check the disassembly.

Comment: If you look at the assembly code you see calls to `_objc_release` in the ARC version, but not in the non-ARC version.

Comment: No no,I use ARC in my work,I just want to know the reason about this..@ ArtSabintsev

Comment: Got it, @ZinLu. As myself, and everyone else said, it's taken care of in the background :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code compiled with ARC has to interoperate with code that wasn't compiled with ARC. Furthermore, you can't assume that Foundation and, in particular, the methods of `NSString` that you're calling, were compiled with ARC.

Those `NSString` methods have to be compiled in such a way that they can be called from both ARC and non-ARC code. That means that they must autorelease the objects they return, whether or not they themselves were compiled with ARC.

However, if those `NSString` methods are compiled with ARC, then they may use `objc_autoreleaseReturnValue()` to do the autoreleasing. If the caller was also compiled with ARC and it retains the object (because, for example, it is assigned to a strong local variable), then it will likely use `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue()` on it. In that case, the use of the autorelease pool can be avoided. `objc_autoreleaseReturnValue()` can detect that the caller will use `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue()` on the returned value, by examining the stack and the caller's instructions, and it won't autorelease the value and it will communicate that fact through a side channel to `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue()` so that it doesn't retain the value.

So, in certain specific circumstances that you can't rely on determining yourself, code that would "normally" autorelease and then retain an object won't. It will simply transfer ownership.

ARC **does not** automatically drain the autorelease pool or introduce inner autorelease pools.

Because of the uncertainties, you should always use `@autoreleasepool` around any code that has a chance of spiking memory due to autoreleased objects. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) @autoreleasepool {
    NSString *string = @"Abc";
    string = [string lowercaseString];
    string = [string stringByAppendingString:@"xyz"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with ARC memory management is automated. But it is not always doing it the right way. Especially in a loop where many temp objects are created.

Temporary objects are objects that are created and used in the current iteration only. Like small strings that are appended to a bigger string.

These temp objects are freed **after** the loop completed, which might be too late. Thats why you have to put the body of your loop in an `@autoreleasepool`, to ensure the objects are freed immediately after each iteration of your loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"];
    }
}
```

Further reading: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Comment: "temp objects"?  Can't you be more precise?

Comment: I added a paragraph with a brief explanation.

Comment: Well I was hoping you'd refer to them as `autorelease` rather than "temp".

Answer (score 0):

With ARC, the compiler is getting smarter.

Before ARC, methods like lowercaseString would create a retained/autoreleased object that is put into an autorelease pool. With ARC, the compiler is smart: lowercaseString checks that the method calling it immediately retains the result. In that case you would have a sequence retain / autorelease / retain, and in that case lowercaseString won't do it's retain / autorelease at all, so only the retain by the caller will be performed. That's faster (it saves a retain, and an autorelease, and the final release when the autorelease pool is closed), and the autorelease pool doesn't grow excessively.

That said, code that only works because the compiler performs an optimisation, is broken.